# How to apply rollover sound

Tags: javascript

Pretty simple question, does anybody know how to add rollover sound to a button on a webpage. Like i'll just move my mouse over a button and a quick sound will be played. Im using Dreaweaver CS5.5 if that is of any help.

Comment: Don't.  They're really annoying.

Comment: On *rollover*? Please no! maybe on click, but definitely not on rollover! It's like mandatory annoyance.

Comment: I gave you a thumbs up because the question is still a valid one. Since you're only doing this for school, you didn't deserve the thumbs down.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds incredibly annoying, but maybe you have some very unusual use case.

The best way is to use the html5 audio tag - just stick the tag somewhere, then call the play() method of it when you want to play it.

If you want it to work in ancient browsers, you'll need some flash fallback, though using flash to play a rollover sound is kind of like annoying^2.

Comment: cheers man and yeh i know they're annoyning but its for an assignment so if it keeps the mark scheme happy then fine

Comment: Impeccable use of arithmetic.

Comment: When will colleges/web design schools realize that this isn't year 2000 anymore?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Rich said, you will also want to preload the audio so that the sound doesn't play some time after the rollover (which would be even more annoying than the sound itself).

There are a number of ways to do this, but I've found that the best way is to set the sound's volume to 0, play it (which forces a load), and once the sound finishes (or on rollover), set the volume to 1.

Again, you really, really should not have sounds playing on your website unless users knowingly invoke and have reason to hear a sound (such as a podcast or a game).

---

Edit: Added some sample code:

```
    <div onmouseover="playAudio()">Some Div</div>

    <audio id="audio_element" src="sound.mp3"></audio>
    <script>
        var audio = document.getElementById("audio_element");
        audio.volume = 0;
        audio.play();

        function playAudio() {

            audio.currentTime = 0.01;
            audio.volume = 1;
            audio.play();

        }
    </script>
```

Comment: where the bit where i put the button or image name i apply this too ?

Comment: @user1243542 When the mouse enters the div element at the top, the sound should play for browsers that support the audio format.